# retrieve corelationId of JMS message in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have created a queue in activeMQ and also created a proxy service which is listening for messages on that queue.

While testing, I have put up a sample message to ActiveMQ queue using the console provided by ActiveMQ and set its corelationId but I am unable to retrieve the same corelation ID in the proxy service.

Below is the proxy code to retrieve the same.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JMSQueueConsumer"
       transports="jms"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
    <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="corelationId" expression="get-property('JMS_COORELATION_ID')"/>
         </log>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">WSO2InQueue</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

In the logs I am getting the value of "corelationId" as null.

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will find this corelationId in the transport scope :

```
get-property('transport','JMS_COORELATION_ID')
```